# Is there a Python 3 console plugin for gedit?

Tags: ubuntu, python, console, gedit

I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu and am settling into a new text-editor; `gedit`.

With its plugins, gedit is surprisingly capable.
I thought I would need to run`"Notepad++ in Wine"`, but the whole Ubuntu experience has thrown that idea out the wndow... (as there is simply no need to hang on to Notepad++).

Come to think of it, I've thrown Windows out the window, too... thanks to my Windows box dying. :)

One thing which a `gedit` plugin can do is to run an embedded `Python console`.
I have tried a couple, but they seem to only cater to `Python 2`.
(I do have Python 3 installed)

Is there a `gedit` plugin which fires up a `Python 3` console?

Thanks.

Comment: I find `gedit` surprisingly good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is.

[Better Python Console](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/BetterPythonConsole)

Actualy there are a lot of good plugins for development on Gedit. Take a look at http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins .

Comment: I have tried `Better Python Console`. It presented me with Python 2 in its console. Perhaps there is some config tweaking I need to do to tell gedit  which Python version to use... but I don't know how to do this.  (Also, `Better Python Console` runs in a seperate window, via F5. Is this really any different to binding IDLE to F5?)...  It is all new to me... all comments are welcome.

Comment: Ubuntu comes with 2.6.x as default. did you install version 3 of python manualy? if so you need to tell the system which verstion to use.

Comment: also, ubuntu specific question may have better answers on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/ which is a sister site of superuser.com

Comment: I used Synaptic Package Manager to install Python 3 and IDLE (for Python 3).  Aside from that, I've done nothing else, as I don't know what to do. I was a reluctant to change a system setting which would override Ubuntu's default Python interpreter, as there may be pre-installed scripts which rely on it being 2.x...  Thanks for the tip about ubuntu.stackexchange.

Comment: The first link is broken...